# Gridsome project hosted on netlify. On click, pages dont load even though the URL does update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, netlify, gridsome

My site deployed is deployed on Netlify and when clicking on any link on the landing page, the url updates but the content does not show unless i refresh the page. note on my local development server this is not an issue. Its only an issue on the live site

Note: there is not much literature on this. On the https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues , Issue #324 and issue #337 both raised the same issue though the answers are not applicable in my project.

1)check out the live site at ezrasnashim.netlify.com. 
Try click on any links on the landing page

**Environment**

@gridsome/cli v0.3.1
gridsome v0.7.12

browser:
firefox developer browser, 
google chrome browser

Comment: also using tailwind css. forgot to add that to the environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through the site, I found the issue was some invalid HTML, which the browser *fixes* [changes around], which changed the actual DOM from the virtual DOM, which caused the Vue hydration to break.

See [Vue SSR hydration caveats](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html#hydration-caveats)

Comment: you are a genius. thanks. though i dont understand why there were no hydration issues in development. On my local server the site was running fine

Comment: I think "gridsome development" runs stuff in memory/on the fly so there are no hydration issues. You can simulate netlify by using "gridsome build" and then serve the dist folder locally, with, for example "http-server".