# Netlify app changes URL when a link is clicked, but takes a second click to actually load the page

Tags: vue.js, netlify, gridsome

So I built a gridsome app using vue.js, and when I developed it locally, everything worked exactly as I needed it.

I then run `gridsome build` and upload the resulting dist folder to Netlify, and deploy the app. The app works as it should, except that when you click on a link at the top, it loads the URL and favicon in the URL bar, but doesn't load the page. It requires a second click to actually load the page. See here: https://65bbaea1b3ac8a15c757b9c4--juliandouglas.netlify.app/

I have looked at various answers, and some of them pointed to:

- changing `v-if` to `v-show`
- fixing erroneous HTML

I have tried both of these, and I can't find any HTML that would break the site.

Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/julian-douglas/portfolio-site which includes the dist folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried changing the `v-if` to `v-show`, but still faced the same issue.

I looked at this: [Gridsome project hosted on netlify. On click, pages dont load even though the URL does update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960451/gridsome-project-hosted-on-netlify-on-click-pages-dont-load-even-though-the-ur) - regarding hydration issues: I also tried scouring my files for erroneous HTML but couldn't find any.